# Arithmetic expression to expression tree

Tags: tree, expression

I am going over a study guide in preparation for an exam and wanted to make sure that I was doing this problem correctly because my teacher is not giving us the study guide solutions. I couldn't really find much on google or youtube about converting arithmetic expressions to expression trees but I gave it my best shot given what I know. Thanks in advance for your time!!

Link to a picture of my work:

http://i64.tinypic.com/i3uuj8.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct.  Try looking at https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse326/03wi/lectures/RaoLect6.pdf for more details.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your quick response and the reference. Hope you have a happy holidays!